# Tab Button Begins Editing Wrong Text Field

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, uiresponder

I have a `UIViewController`, **VC** with some elements on it, 2 of which are `UITextField`s. There is a button that, upon the users touch, presents a new controller `CustomAlertViewController`, **VCAlert** over the current VC with a modal presentation style of `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext`.

In this **VCAlert** I have 3 text fields.

---

When I press the tab key on my bluetooth keyboard, initially it **only** toggles through the 2 text fields on **VC**, even **after** presenting **VCAlert**, which is now the top-most presented view controller.

This is the important bit:

> AFTER I tap one of the 3 fields on **VCAlert**, pressing the
>   tab button correctly toggles through the 3 fields on the top-most view
>   controller, now ignoring the input fields in the view controller underneath.

---

> - Is there a way to tell **VCAlert** (the top-most presented view controller) to listen for the tab button events, and NOT the parent controller any longer (until of course **VCAlert** is dismissed)?

*I would like to accomplish this without having to remove the delegates from the 2 VC text fields, OR removing them from the view.*

**CODE:**

The code is extremely straightforward... so it will be limited.

Each `UITextView` has its delegate registered to the respective view controller. The **VCAlert** controller is presented in the following way:

```
// Here, self is the VC, and alertViewController is VCAlert

[self presentViewController:alertViewController animated:NO completion:^{

    // Do absolutely nothing here like usual

}];
```

---

**FYI:**

I have tried called `becomeFirstResponder` on one of the text fields in **VCAlert** then immediately called `resignFirstResponder`, but it doesn't make the tab bar toggle them - it still toggles the fields on the view controller below.

Comment: I confirmed this behaviour with a test project on iOS Simulator, unfortunately no solution found too, did you try pushing your alert VC instead of modal presentation?

Comment: I will look into that, but unfortunately I need the over current context appearance